# Python : Pivot up values in data frame using lamda

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a text file and using pandas and storing the details in Data Frame. Below is the Input file on which data frame is created :

```
SourceID|OrganizationName|AddressLine1|AddressLine2|City  
1|Manor Drug Medical And Pharma|5795 N 1st St||Uta  
1|Manor Drug Medical And Pharma|23230 Red River|Dr Ste 104|Evanston
```

On this data frame i am trying to pivot up the address information grouping by SourceID. Below is the expected output:

```
SourceID|OrganizationName|AddressLine1|AddressLine2|City
1|Manor Drug Medical And Pharma|5795 N 1st St^23230 Red River|^Dr Ste 104|Evanston^Uta
```

Below is the code used for same:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('PivotingValues.txt', sep="|")


a=df[df.groupby("SourceID")['AddressLine1'].apply(lambda tags: '^'.join(tags)),  df.groupby("SourceID")['City'].apply(lambda tags: '^'.join(tags))]

print(a)
```

Can you please help is achieving the same. Is there any other method other then lamda that can be used to achieve the same

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
df.groupby(['SourceID', 'OrganizationName'], as_index = False).agg('^'.join)
```

**OR**

```
df.groupby(['SourceID', 'OrganizationName'], as_index = False).agg({'AddressLine1': '^'.join, 'AddressLine2': '^'.join, 'City': '^'.join})
```

**Output**

```
    SourceID    OrganizationName    AddressLine1    AddressLine2    City
       1    Manor Drug Medical And Pharma   5795 N 1st St^23230 Red River   ^Dr Ste 104 Uta^Evanston
```

Comment: Hi Vivek, Thanks for your reply but executing the 2nd option is throwing error :-  "    f = lambda x: func(x, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found"

Comment: @AKASHSENGAR impute missing values with blank with `fillna('')`. Basically you want `str` columns